# Arduino compiling as C++, not C

Tags: c++, c, compilation, arduino

I'm trying to use a Supermodified Servo on an Arduino.

I don't have any actual code in my sketch yet, I'm just trying to compile the library. I get a ton of errors .

After doing some research, I figured out that if I were to compile my code as C as opposed to C++, I wouldn't be getting these errors. But I have no idea how to do that!

I'm using Arduino 1.0 for Linux x64.

@Omnifarious I only have the #include directive in my arduino sketch, which at this time is `sketch_jan20.cpp`

I added

```
#ifd __cplusplus{
extern "C"
#endif
```

That helped get rid of the errors below, except for one of them: the redefinition of the boolean. When I commented that line out, I got a whole new mess of errors. All of them were the same, consisting of some variation of:

`C:\Users\Ventrius\Programming\Arduino1.01\libraries\ArduinoApiC\/zoCommands.h:131: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'zoCommandDoMove'`

**Errors:**

```
avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=100 -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC /tmp/build3069866408398264713.tmp/sketch_jan20a.cpp -o/tmp/build3069866408398264713.tmp/sketch_jan20a.cpp.o 
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoSmsMaster.h:4:0,
                 from sketch_jan20a.cpp:1:
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoTypes.h:39:18: error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type ‘bool’
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoSmsMaster.h:5:0,
                 from sketch_jan20a.cpp:1:
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:19:29: error: non-local function ‘void zoErrorInit(volatile ZO_ERROR*)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:20:27: error: non-local function ‘u08 zoErrorGet(volatile ZO_ERROR*)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:21:44: error: non-local function ‘void zoErrorPut(volatile ZO_ERROR*, u08)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:22:32: error: non-local function ‘bool zoErrorIsEmpty(volatile ZO_ERROR*)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:24:30: error: non-local function ‘u08 zoErrorGetIsr(volatile ZO_ERROR*)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:25:47: error: non-local function ‘void zoErrorPutIsr(volatile ZO_ERROR*, u08)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoSmsMaster.h:6:0,
                 from sketch_jan20a.cpp:1:
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoProtocol.h:93:26: error: non-local function ‘bool zoProtocolCommandResponse(ZO_PROTOCOL_HAL*, ZO_PROTOCOL_PACKET*, volatile ZO_ERROR*)’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: error: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
In file included from sketch_jan20a.cpp:1:0:
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoSmsMaster.h:55:18: warning: non-local variable ‘volatile ZO_ERROR* zoSmsMasterError’ uses anonymous type
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ArduinoApiC/zoError.h:15:2: warning: ‘typedef volatile struct<anonymous> ZO_ERROR’ does not refer to the unqualified type, so it is not used for linkage
```

Comment: So, is your code C or C++? It's not really clear. Seems like C to me. Why are you trying to compile this as C++ by the way?

Comment: The Arduino libraries themselves are all compiled as (and use features of) C++. As long as your code is not using anything from these libraries then you should be able to compile it as C.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch: It looks like the OP is purposely using the header files from the Arduino C API.

Comment: Is `sketch_jan20a.cpp` your own file? Does it have anything in it other than `#include` directives?

Comment: Judging by the code glimpses in those errors, the code will most certainly not compile with a standard C compiler. In general I would advise to use a fully compliant standard C or C++ compiler with no language extensions, _especially_ if you are a beginner trying to learn embedded programming.

Comment: @Lundin: It doesn't look like those errors are in the program at all. They're in the Arduino header files. I suspect the `.cpp` file of being empty of anything but `#include` directives.

Comment: You can leave comments down here to reply you know. And I would just rename your file to `.c` then instead of `.cpp` and use `avr-gcc` to compile. It will work fine then. Wrapping your `#include` in `extern "C"` is the wrong thing to do. Arduino seems to have a C++ interface, why do you want to `#include` that specific file?

Comment: It's an included API for a servo motor that I'm using. It's worked in the past, but I haven't touched it in over 2 years. The project is dead on google code.

As for renaming my file, I can't. The Arduino software is set to compile with avr-g++ on it's own. I can't make it save my sketch to a `.c` file. Atleast not as far as I know

Comment: @Windsplunts: Interesting. It looks like there's a C++ interface in the SuperModified.V1 subdirectory. Maybe you should be using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is not very useful, and is just my attempt to deal with the confusing nature of the question.**

Rename your files to `.c` and use `avr-gcc` to compile them, not `avr-g++`.

If you get errors, that means you need to adjust your program, and possibly even re-write it to not use any C++ features.

There is no general formula for translating a C++ program to C.

Another option is to create a C layer of your own for your C++ code to call. This layer of C code will have C++-friendly function definitions (i.e. no `bool` and the like) and it will then call the non-C++-friendly code out of the Arduino libraries.

You can then create header files containing the function definitions for your C layer that are wrapped in `extern "C" {` ... `}`. Make sure those header files do not include any of the header files for the Arduino libraries you're using.